# How to verify if Hibernate c3p0 is working

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

Hello there i have a maven application, im using  java + jersey + hibernate on it.

I have implemented c3p0. On log nothing show me an error, but when i made a test, the jdbc is not creating another connection to others users:

See the statistics() :

```
jul 25, 2018 2:10:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    28898 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    665621 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    70901 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    2902975 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

**Persistence.xml:**

```
<!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/> -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" /> <!-- 5 -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="1" /> <!-- 20  -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="20" /> <!-- 3000 -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="20" /> <!-- 50 -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="20" /> <!-- 300 -->
```

I need to know if im doing something wrong.

**pom.xml:**

```
<!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
```

Comment: What is your issue? It is hard to understand from your question.  You set a max_size to 1 so yes your server should open only one connection for all your users. Except if you have multiple query at the same time where you should have an error like pool is full.

Comment: I was thinking pool connection open a new JDBC connection when max_size is full. Am i wrong?

Comment: max_size 1 mean there is only one connection maximum in the pool. All your users will use the same connection.  If the connection is already in use when another user ask for a connection, you should have a max_wait that specify how much time this user wait before throwing an exception.